# Views proximity search by postal code show all when empty

Tags: views

I'm using proximity search in views 3.

The proximity search is by Postal Code.

When first loading the view page, it's showing all result.
In my case this is not good because the postal code is required for filtering.

My question is.

Is there a way to not showing all the result when postal code search field is empty.

Here is a screen shot of my views Criteria.

[image]

In More
Thanks a lot

Comment: Try changing the _Exposed form style_ to _Input required_.

Comment: it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

In the settings for the exposed search field, you should be able to change the behaviour: 
On Empty input, Show None.  Show All is set by default

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find where it is ?

Comment: Under FILTER CRITERIA, you should have a field that it is using to search by, and it should be an exposed filter. clicking on the settings for that field should bring up the option to include an On Empty input, where you change the behaviour when nothing is entered

Comment: I did a screenshot of What I'm seeing, I'm I at the right place

Comment: it looks like it overwrites some of Views default behaviour. The option doesn't appear to be there. It might need to be a feature request for the module